# How to delete tail in Double Link List?

Tags: java, constructor, linked-list, double, tail

My teacher guides us in this activity on how to delete the tail of the double link list. He created an step by step process or algorithm for us to follow. I followed it, but it doesn't work. Or maybe I am following it wrong. Here is the algorithm

> Check if the list is empty
>
> - If not Empty
>
>   - Check if there is only one node in the list
>
>     - If only one node, set the head and tail reference to null.
>     - if more than one node
>
>       - create a temptail to point to next tail (tail.prev)
>       - set the prev of the tail and next of temptail to null
>       - assign the temptail value to the tail

**Here is my code**

```
    public void delTail(){
    DoubleNode temp;
    
   if(isEmpty()){
       return;
   }
   else if(!isEmpty()){
       if(head == tail){
           head = tail = null;
       }
       else{
            temp = tail.next;
            tail.prev = null;
            temp.next = null;
            temp = tail;
       }
   }
    
}
```

This is the error that i saw [error in my terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEUOA.png)

I think that I am following it right or maybe not? Thank you so much for your help :)

**This is my constructor***

```
public class DoubleNode{

public DoubleNode prev;
public int data;
public DoubleNode next;

public DoubleNode(int d){
    this(null, d, null);
}
public DoubleNode(DoubleNode p, int d, DoubleNode n){
    prev = p;
    data = d;
    next = n;
}
}
```

**this is mt entire operator code***

```
public class operator{
DoubleNode head;
DoubleNode tail;
DoubleNode laman;

String output = "";

public operator(){
    head = tail = null;
}
public boolean isEmpty(){
    return head == null;
}
public void addHead(int i){
    
    if(isEmpty()){
      head = tail =new DoubleNode(i);
    }
    else{
        head = new DoubleNode(null, i, head);
        head.prev = head;
    }
}
public void addTail(int i){
    DoubleNode last = new DoubleNode(i);  
    if(isEmpty()){
        head = tail = new DoubleNode(i);
    }
    else{
      tail.next = last;
      tail = last;
    }
}
public void delHead(){
    DoubleNode temp = head.next; 
    if(head==tail){ //this if condition is testing if the head and tail is one only, 
        head = tail =null;  //if there is only one this will set the tail and head to null
    }
    else{
        head = head.next;
        head = temp;

    }
}

public void delTail(){
        DoubleNode temp;
        if(isEmpty()) {  
            return;  
        }  
        else {  
            if(head != tail) {   
            tail = tail.prev;
            temp = tail;
               
            }
            
            else {  
                head = tail = null;  
            }  
        }  
}
public void display(){
    DoubleNode tmp = head;
    output = "<html>";
    
    for(tmp = head; tmp != null; tmp = tmp.next){
        output = output + "<br>" + tmp.data + "<b>" + "<br>";
        
    }
    output = output + "</html>";
}
}
```

This is my entire code so far, i have a main class with a jframe but i think its fine because i also use it for single link list. But I do have a problem here at double link list regarding on deleting the last node

Comment: I what way doesn't your code work?  What error or issue are you seeing?

Comment: The code snippet doesn't match the pseudo code ... In a DLL tail.next is always going to be null (remember tail is at the end so there is no next).  When deleting the tail `tail.prev` actually points to what you want the tail to be now .. so `tail = tail.prev; tail.next = null;` seems like all you'd need. `temp` is never going to be used - unless you want to save the old `tail` so you can clear out it's `prev' to help with garbage collection.

Comment: does my if else condition work? like is that the problem? I tried every recommendations that i red here but none of it works.

Comment: Note that you have a bunch of other errors in the code you've added: 1) you have double assignments like `head = head.next;  head = temp;` 2) you're not always maintaining `prev` and `next` correctly. Note that when removing `node` you need to point `node.prev.next ` to `node.next` and `node.next.prev` to `node.prev`. When inserting `node` you need to adjust the references as well: `node.next = after.next; node.prev = after; node.next.prev = node; after.next = node;` (`after` would be the node you insert after).

Comment: You also need to think about what you'd do when you only have one node: Should `head == tail` be true? Should `head.next == head` and `head.prev == head` be true? If not then you'd need to handle that special case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two errors in your `else` block:

- You never change the `tail` reference. The last statement should really be an assignment to `tail`.
- You seem to assume that the `tail` has a non-null `next` reference, but that is a contradiction. The tail is supposed to be the last node, so its `next` reference will always be null (unless you are supposed to create a *circular* list). By consequence, `temp` will be null, and the statement `temp.next = tail` will trigger the Null Pointer Exception.

  The more interesting property of `tail` is its `prev` property, which refers to the node that will become the `tail` after the current tail node has been removed. This `tail.prev` is explicitly mentioned in your assignment.

So:

```java
   else {
        temp = tail.prev; // <--- should point to the new tail
        tail.prev = null;
        temp.next = tail;
        tail = temp;  // <--- reverse the assignment
   }
```

### Several other issues...

In `addHead` you do not set the `prev` property correctly. You make it a self-reference. Realise that `head` is already referencing the new node. Change:

```
head.prev = head;
```

to:

```
head.next.prev = head;
```

In `addTail` the assignment to `prev` is missing. Change:

```
tail.next = last;
tail = last;
```

to:

```
tail.next = last;
last.prev = tail; // needed!
tail = last;
```

In `delHead` you must make sure the new head's `prev` is null. So change:

```
head = temp;
```

to:

```
head = head.next;
head.prev = null;
```

NB: you don't need `DoubleNode temp = head.next;` in that method.

Comment: i copy this exact code and try to use the logic that u gave because it does makes sense. But it seems like my code can't determine where are the tail.prev?

Comment: What do you mean with that? I suppose you have a class that defines both `prev` and `next`, right? Can you edit your question and add the constructor code?

Comment: I already edit and add my constructor as u told

Comment: Several issues in your code. See addition to answer.

Comment: I copy the codes that you gave me for the addHead, addTail and delHead all of it works but it seems like i can't solve my problem with the delTail. And the head.next.prev = head, it confuse me and i really want to know how it works

Comment: i just solve the delTail thank you so much sir for helping me. I solve the delTail just now, Thank you so much, sir :)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're just assigning to `temp` but don't actually use it. Additionally you're not setting the link back to the previous element correctly.

Assuming `tail.next` points to `head` again you might do the following:

```
tail.prev.next = tail.next; //you might need to check for `tail.prev` being null 
tail.next.prev = tail.prev; //you might need to check for `tail.next` being null
//delete tail
```

To illustrate:

```
A -next-> Tail -next-> Head
^---prev--+  ^---prev--+
```

Step 1:

```
+----next--------------V
A         Tail -next-> Head
^---prev--+  ^---prev--+
```

Step 2:

```
+----next--------------V
A         Tail -next-> Head
^---prev--+            |
^--------------prev----+
```

Actually if `tail.next == head` removing the tail is no different than removing any other node.

Comment: i try to do your instructions? But can you check my if and else condition above? Is it too much or necessary for my code?

Comment: @Bianxzy It depends on whether you actually want `head` and `tail` to point to each other. If so, you basically just need the following checks: `head == null` (in that case `tail` should be null as well) means the list is empty. `head == tail` means you only have one element and can just remove it. Anything else means you need to handle the `prev` and `next` references.

Comment: it seems like my code can't find the tail.prev reference and when i do head.next = null; The entire number that i enter will be deleted except the head. Dang! I am stuck with this for 2 days already. I know i gotta be a programmer i can do this

Comment: @Bianxzy well, it is hard to tell what's happening without knowing what exactly you are doing. Accessing `tail.prev` should be independent from `head.next = null`. - To solve this yourself you should learn how to step through your code with a debugger and see what it is really doing.